# Using a Azure Devops python artifact repo on a Microsoft machine learning server

Tags: azure-devops, pip, microsoft-machine-learning-server

I have a SQL Server 2017 instance with Machine Learning services install in database. I have a custom module that I have a wheels package built and published to a Azure Devops python artifact repo that I can install from other machines using the Azure Artifacts keyring module to authenticate.

I want to setup my machine learning server so I can `pip install` from this azure devops package repo, but after I install the keyring and artifacts-keyring modules per the documentation and try to `pip install` with the `-i` option to specify the url to my azure devops package repo I get prompted to authenticate with my username/password. This is different behavior on my development machines (and does not work), on those machines the keyring modules authenticate me automatically.

Looking at the [github](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-keyring) page for the artifacts-keyring module it looks like I need pip 19.2 or greater, and the machine learning server has pip 9.0.1. Running  `.\pip.exe install --upgrade pip` from the PYTHON_SERVICES directory gives me an error:

```
 The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: 'e:\\program files\\microsoft sql server\\mssql14.mssqlserver\\python_services\\scripts\\pip.exe' -> 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7\\pip-qxx3khcz-uninstall\\program files\\microsoft sql server\\mssql14.mssqlserver\\python_services\\scripts\\pip.exe
```

Going further down the rabbit hole, it looks like i might need to [unbind/bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/upgrade-r-and-python?view=sql-server-2017) the updated binaries. Has anyone configured their MS machine learning server to use a azure devops python artifact repo as a pip index? Should I approach deploying my modules a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did which worked for me:

Stop all of the SQL server services. I think I would have only needed to stop the Jumpstart service though.

Run the basic [get-pip.py script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) from the PYTHON_SERVICES directory that the ML server is using. This installed the latest version of pip, as verified with `.\Scripts\pip.exe -V`

I then ran `.\Scripts\pip.exe install keyring artifacts-keyring`

I then installed my module from my index/repo `.\Scripts\pip.exe install -i https://myIndexURL/ MyModule`

Brought all the SQL services up and confirmed I can use my module.